# Add Child Behind existing object AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, addchild

I have made a game using Flash CS5 (as3) and I am trying to add a child to the stage behind objects that are already there. For example, I have a bar at the bottom of the screen that is there from the time you start the game and I have falling objects that I want to fall behind it, but instead they fall in front of it because I added them to the stage after. Is there a way of adding the falling objects behind it without having to keep re-adding the bar to the stage? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Sprites to act as layers, and add the different objects to them. Here is an example that adds a layer for adding whatever you want behind the bar layer, and THEN adds the bar layer, so it will be on top. It's super rough since you don't have any code to reference:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.*;
    public class Test extends MovieClip {

        var barLayer:Sprite;
        var objectLayer:Sprite;

        public function Test() {

            var objectLayer = new Sprite();
            //add the object layer to your main Class
            this.addChild(objectLayer);

            //now you can add movie clips or sprites to objectLayer whenever you like

            //then create the bar layer
            var barLayer = new Sprite();

            //add your bar Display Object here
            var bar = new MovieClip();//draw the bar or reference the library object you've created
            barLayer.addChild(bar);

            //now add the barLayer
            this.addChild(barLayer);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also I was wondering if adding children is better or just putting them graphically onto the stage for the bar. The bar has a few different movie clips connected to it.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do as the flash file plays. Adding them to the stage is totally fine, and you can still reference them via instance name from the code if you want.

Comment: I have about 10 different graphics that I want over the falling child I added those to the stage without adding them as children. I just dropped them on the stage. Is there a way of putting the child behind them without doing anything to the other objects that are not children. or should I just make them children and add them that way.

Comment: ok, so you have a bunch of objects on the stage and you want to put them over another object on the stage? If that's the case, then just put them in their own layer on the stage and manipulate the hierarchy there.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than layering, I'd use adjust the index of each object using addChildAt and setChildIndex.

The following line adds your falling object behind every other DisplayObject on the stage (in this case, you should probably add your bar to the stage first)

```
stage.addChildAt(fallingObject, 0);
```